# How can I use to_char function in the Liferay DynamicQuery API?

Tags: java, sql, liferay, liferay-7, dynamicquery

**Platform is Liferay 7.0, Tomcat, Oracle 12c.**

We currently use dynamic query below. In order to tune it for better performance, we need to convert the data_ field which is a CLOB to character.

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil
                    .forClass(ExpandoValue.class, PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader())
                    .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("columnId").eq(GetterUtil.getLong(column.getColumnId())))
                    .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("data").like(somecharvalue))
                    .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("classNameId")
                            .eq(GetterUtil.getLong(ClassNameLocalServiceUtil.getClassNameId(User.class.getName()))));
```

At runtime, it results in SQL query below which we need to tune:

```
SELECT this_.valueId AS valueId90_0_,
this_.companyId AS companyId90_0_,
this_.tableId AS tableId90_0_,
this_.columnId AS columnId90_0_,
this_.rowId_ AS rowId5_90_0_,
this_.classNameId AS classNam6_90_0_,
this_.classPK AS classPK90_0_,
this_.data_ AS data8_90_0_
FROM ExpandoValue this_
WHERE this_.columnId = NNNNN AND this_.data_ LIKE '%CCCC%' AND this_.classNameId = NNNNN
```

How can I add the to_char(data_) to the SQL query above using DynamicQuery or other API for liferay 7 so it looks like below?

```
SELECT this_.valueId AS valueId90_0_,
this_.companyId AS companyId90_0_,
this_.tableId AS tableId90_0_,
this_.columnId AS columnId90_0_,
this_.rowId_ AS rowId5_90_0_,
this_.classNameId AS classNam6_90_0_,
this_.classPK AS classPK90_0_,
this_.data_ AS data8_90_0_
FROM ExpandoValue this_
WHERE this_.columnId = NNNNN AND to_char(this_.data_) LIKE '%CCCC%' AND this_.classNameId = NNNNN
```

Thanks for all the insight!

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Comment: I could not solve it by using the DynamicQuery. I had to use a direct SQL query to the database to be able to do this.